# Connect AWS redis to node using node-redis

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, redis, node-redis

I am using node-redis and having a hard time connecting to external redis instance. I tried with redis-cli and it worked. However with node I am not able to figure out how to properly give the url and port.

**With Redis-cli-**

```
redis-cli -h mydomain.something.something.cache.amazonaws.com -p 6379
```

**However with nodejs**

Below didn't work

```
var client = redis.createClient('redis://mydomain.something.something.cache.amazonaws.com:6379'),
```

neither

```
var client = redis.createClient({host:'redis://mydomain.something.something.cache.amazonaws.com', port: 6379});
```

How do I configure it. Please help.

Comment: Your second code example looks correct. Are you running the node app on the same server that you tested connecting with `redis-cli`?

Comment: Yes. Is there any other way also to give this parameters?

Comment: You could try `redis.createClient(6379, 'mydomain.something.something.cache.amazonaws.com')` but I don't think it's going to make a difference. Are you getting any error messages when you test the node app?

Comment: Wait, will post that too. Have to look for logs.

Comment: Have you checked your security groups on AWS to make sure that servers have access to connect to Redis. It might also be worth pointing out that you are not able to connect to your Redis instances from outside of AWS network. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonElastiCache/latest/UserGuide/Access.Outside.html#Access.Outside.HowTo

Comment: I have the exact same problem, did you find a solution @scripter

Comment: @martin just use like this var client = redis.createClient(6379, 'domain.something.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com');      It worked for me.

Comment: @scripter my problem was the security group of the cache, thanks though

Comment: Which npm version using @scripter

Answer (score 4):

Following should work with node.js -

```
var client = require('redis').createClient(6379, 'elastichache endpoint string', {
        no_ready_check: true
     });
```

Also, make sure that your security group on AWS allows you to access the database.

Answer (score 1):

```
var client = require('redis').createClient(6379, 'elastichache endpoint string', {
        no_ready_check: true
     });
```

With the above code, it was always trying to connect with localhost,

Below code worked for me.

```
var client = require('redis').createClient(
  {
    url:  `redis://${elasticCacheConnectionString}`,
  }
);
```

Please note, i have appended `redis://` as communication protocol before actual connection string.

FYI: I am using `redis@4.1.0` version.